# Windows Phone 8: Will a BackGroundAgent run when phone is in idle state?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an app in which the user can enable Secondary Tiles to get updated data on the home screen. I have registered a PeriodicTask that is connecting to a web service for retrieving information and updating the Tiles - this then runs at an approximate 30 minute interval, as expected.

However, I only need to update the data when the handset is active, as when the user opens the lock-screen after beeing idle. There is no point in updating the tiles when the user is not present, but I want it to update as soon as the user activates the homescreen/unlocks the screen (still minding the 30 minute constraint of course).

So, my question is this: Do BackgroundAgents run even when the phone is idle/black screen? And if so, is there any way to prevent this?

I find the documentation a bit thin on this topic: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BackgroundAgents run every 30 minutes no matter what (except for battery saver). You can add condition and stop the execution maybe when it is night time, but you cannot determine if user interacted with phone or how long the phone is in idle.